# wait for results in loop with ordering

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, std

Trying to parralelize computing method, then wait for collecting result from all computations and store them in std::list with other data injection, so don't see performance improvements. Maybe if I know 'num_results' I can merge both cycles and store data in list only via locking (mutex) write (push_back) procedure somehow? Other thing is how to preserve order (if on some [i] computation is fast)
Doing this in one cycle in one core is too slow.

```
// here is pseudocode 

void SomeClass::SomeMethod() {
  size_t num_results = request_list.size();
  std::list<result_t> some_results;
  float *result = new float[num_results];
  // linearly I do one for in where one parameter of list pushing are long computing function
  // so I create array of function results and try to store data same time then wait and collect in list with other data
  for (size_t i(0); i < num_results; i++) {
     // Calculate is hard function and may vary in times depending on imput
     // use temporary thread object and labda function to acces class members data
     thread t([&]() { result[i] = Calculate(request_list[i]); });
     // where or how to wait for all results stored in array only then push them to list?

     t.join(); // where or how to wait for all result[] for next cycle or merge both? 
  } 
  // conjugate result with some other data from static list with same id's
  for (std::size_t i(0); i < num_requests; i++) {
      some_results.push_back( result_t(result[i], other_data[i], ...) );
  }

  delete [] result; // free memory

   // Continue job with some_results list

}
```

Is I'm doing parralelism wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `join` function again, you start a thread for calculating, wait for that thread and start another thread after this. Instead you should start multiple threads and join them afterwards. Your order of operations is wrong because you wait for each thread.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/

Comment: how can I make this joins if it's in loop?

Comment: you need to create the threads before the loop and join them afterwards

Comment: I gues to use std::async maybe, because I don't know exactly count of threads (num_results may vary from 1 to 15) :( so it's impossible to create them without loop

Comment: maybe use a threadpool with a fixed amount of threads then. But it's way harder to implement and you may need a library for it

Comment: I found solution with calling calc method as parameter of std::async and pushing them to std::list<future> then just while cycle that wait for valid method of list of that futures and popping them from future list and adding to vector of results same time. Now it runs momentally. Also seems auto f = [&]() { return Calc; } then pass f as param of std::async works better than direct passing, dunno why lambda function dies rather than thread starts and it was one of UB problems in code upwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
// solution for dynamic async threads with store results 
// after lots of documentation reading of multithreading
// function do asynchronic calls of N count of heavy ops then waits in idle 
// cycle to aquire all results, if first is ready push it to vector
// while it waits for first result accesible, next maybe ready allready    


void SomeClass::SomeMethod() {
   auto request_util = [&](std::size_t i) { return Calculate(i); };
   size_t num_results = request_list.size();
   std::list<std::future<float>> request_respond_list;
   for (std::size_t i(0); i < num_requests; i++)
      request_respond_list.push_back( std::async(std::launch::async, request_util, i));

   std::size_t id(0);

   // example of result storing
   // float *result = new float[num_results];
   std::vector< result_t > results;
   while (!request_respond_list.empty()) {
      if (request_respond_list.front().valid()) {
          results.push_back(result_t(request_respond_list.front().get(), other_data[id]));
          request_respond_list.pop_front();
          id++;
      } else
         std::this_thread::yield();
   } request_respond_list.clear();

  // do other job with results vector
   ....
}
```